# Indentation of list constants

Tags: indentation

Emacs' indentation of Emacs lisp code is really great, except for one thing:

```
(defconst one-to-ten '(one two three
                           four five six seven
                           eight nine ten))
```

Is this actually the preferred way to indent this block? As opposed to

```
(defconst one-to-ten '(one two three
                       four five six seven
                       eight nine ten))
```

I find it especially confusing when compared to the default for alists:

```
(defconst one-to-ten '((one . 1) (two . 2) (three . 3)
                       (four . 4) (five . 5) (six . 6) (seven . 7)
                       (eight . 8) (nine . 9) (ten . 10)))
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour? I could possibly understand it for back-quoted lists, as it would yield better indentation for macros, but what about lists?

Comment: The [coding conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html) section of the manual is pretty explicit about this, btw: `Indent the file using the default indentation parameters.`

Comment: The coding conventions might say that by convention we respect the default indentation, but that does not provide a reason **why** the default indentation is what it is. There is nothing in the coding conventions that says why a constant list is indented as it is. (This is akin to an overtired parent replying, in response to the 99th "Why?", "*Just because*".)

Comment: @Drew, aren't `coding conventions` by definition a collection of, for better or worse, conventions?

Comment: @EmacsUser: Of course. What's your point? The question asked was "*Is there a reason for this behaviour?*" **Why** this indentation convention? Conventions don't fall out of the sky. And sometimes they are changed. If the only answer given to *Why?* is "*That's the convention*", that's no answer at all.

Comment: @Drew, since conventions don't have to justify a reason, my point is why even ask "why?" Just go and change it if there's a good reason. No tired parents here holding you back.

Comment: @EmacsUser: No one has argued against your "point". The question is a good one. There may be good reasons for having picked this default. Or not. There might be reasons for an alternative indentation. Nothing wrong with asking the question.

Comment: @Clément: FWIW, I personally think this is a bug and there's been changes around this part of Elisp-mode "recently", so you might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the settings I'm using to fix the indentation:

```cl
(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)
(eval-after-load 'cl-indent
  `(progn
     (put 'cl-flet 'common-lisp-indent-function
          (get 'flet 'common-lisp-indent-function))
     (put 'cl-labels 'common-lisp-indent-function
          (get 'labels 'common-lisp-indent-function))
     (put 'if 'common-lisp-indent-function 2)))
```

I tried to fix the Elisp indentation at one point, but it was too convoluted and I gave up.  But the settings above have worked fine for years.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what those `put` and `get` forms do? Does it replace the `cl-flet` function instances with `flet` and `cl-labels` instances with `labels` only in the `common-lisp-indent-function`? If so, why is that done? Also what does the third put do? I read the `put` documentation but still did not make sense. It would translate to "set the value of `common-lisp-indent-function` property of `if` symbol to 2" but that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: In these 3 cases, `'lisp-indent-function` (i.e. the default one) is actually better than `'common-lisp-indent-function`. Those settings make the indentation carry over from one to the other.

Comment: **Note:** It is only the first line that answers this question -- i.e., `(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)`. The rest has nothing to do with the indentation to use for a constant list.